# Different layouts for portrait and landscape modes based on screen width, not orientation per se

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two versions of my layout, for smaller screens and for larger screens. Incidentally, I have a device where different layouts are required in different orientations. On other device that may not be so. I want to base it on screen width, not the orientation as such.

I've read [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) and noticed that the "Available screen width" (`w<N>dp` modifier) can be used for specifying the proper layouts. It also says:

> The system's corresponding value for the width changes when the screen's orientation switches between landscape and portrait to reflect the current actual width that's available for your UI.

Sounds perfect. So I put the smaller layout in the base `layout` folder, and the larger one into `layout-w750dp`. And the larger layout is picked. The problem is that it doesn't switch to the base layout when I rotate the device into portrait mode.

I have used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755265/634821) to check the screen width in dp. It's 960 in landscape and 600 in portrait. Then I made sure `android:configChanges="orientation"` is *not* specified for this activity. I have also put `Log` into this activity's `onCreate()` - it is indeed called when I rotate the device, so it should have received the correct layout?.. Why doesn't it work and how to make it work?

**Update**: launching the activity (and even the whole application) in portrait mode right from the start still picks the `w750dp` layout.

**Update 2**: `layout-land` didn't work either. This layout is still picked in the portrait mode. Odd. It's becoming clear that the issue has little to do with width but with general functioning of the resource selectors.

Comment: You need `res/layout-land` folder for landscape

Comment: @cricket_007: that's exactly what I don't want to do. Did you read the question?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157971/have-a-fixed-orientation-based-on-screen-size

Comment: Do you have something else in `android:configChanges`?

Comment: @makvasic: no, this particular activity only has its name in the manifest, nothing else. Also, please see the update I edited into the bottom of my question. This problem may not be related to orientation change at all.

Comment: You can add screen width into the landscape resources, was my point

Comment: @cricket_007: I understand. And my point was that there should be a way to avoid dividing layouts into landscape and portrait in the first place. All my layout cares about is width, it doesn't care which of your screen's sides is the longer side.

Comment: That's really strange... try maybe `layout-w750dp-land` just to see what happens...

Comment: @makvasic: good test. It did *not* work. Any idea why?

Comment: I have no more ideas other then trying to get smallest width with this [method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23900692/7177329) and see what that gives you but i doubt that is less then 750dp :/

Comment: @makvasic: that's what I used. It gave 600dp for portrait mode width, that's why I picked 750 as the threshold.

Comment: I am intrigued... Will make same sample project to test this and see what happens!

Comment: @makvasic: Thanks! I thought maybe it's because I was renaming the folders using the Android Studio itself, maybe something didn't register. So I restarted the Studio, and nope, still no dice. And yes, I did check for typos :)

Answer (score 1):

Comments are getting long so to answer.
I just tested on tablet (768x1024 dp) two layouts first in `layout`, second in `layout-w900dp` and everything works just fine.
Second layout is shown in landscape mode which is correct because 900 < 1024.

**Note**: I used `getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp` for screen width!

So it's definitely problem on your side :)
Ether you messed up your layouts or android studio messing with you :D.

Sorry for lack of more definitive answer :/

Comment: I see. Very odd. Thanks for testing.